# Derivative of a Matrix w.r.t. its Matrix Square, $\frac{\partial \text{vec}X}{\partial\text{vec}(XX')}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, jacobian

Let $X$ be a nonsingular square matrix.

What is
$$
\frac{\partial \text{vec}X}{\partial\text{vec}(XX')},
$$
where the vec operator stacks all columns of a matrix in a single column vector?

It is easy to derive that
$$
\frac{\partial\text{vec}(XX')}{\partial \text{vec}X} = (I + K)(X \otimes I),
$$
where $K$ is the commutation matrix that is defined by
$$
\text{vec}(X) = K\text{vec}(X').
$$

Now $(I + K)(X \otimes I)$ is a singular matrix, so that the intuitive solution
$$
\frac{\partial \text{vec}X}{\partial\text{vec}(XX')} = \left( \frac{\partial\text{vec}(XX')}{\partial \text{vec}X} \right)^{-1}
$$
does not work.

Is the solution simply the Moore-Penrose inverse of $(I + K)(X \otimes I)$, or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following QR, SVD, and Cholesky factorizations.
$$\eqalign{
X^T &= QR \quad&\implies\quad A = R^T \\
X &= U\Sigma V^T \quad&\implies\quad B = U\Sigma \\
XX^T &= LL^T \\
}$$
Thus there are (at least) four ways to write the product
$$\eqalign{
P = XX^T = AA^T = BB^T = LL^T \\
}$$
In other words, given $P$ and the functional form $XX^T$ there is no way to uniquely determine $X$, which is why your gradient has no inverse $-$ it doesn't exist.

On the other hand, given $X$ one can calculate $XX^T$ unambiguously, which is why your first gradient exists.

Comment: Thank you very much, @greg!